# Attempt to index field ? (a nil value)

Tags: arrays, lua, 2d, lua-table, love2d

I am writing a small RPG game engine with Lua/love2d, and I need to parse a file to a 2d array, but it don't work, and I am getting errors...

main.lua :

```
local fmap = love.filesystem.read("map.txt")
map = {}
for c in fmap:gmatch(".") do
    if c == "\n" then
        y = 0
        x = x + 1
    else
        map[x][y] = c -- this won't work
        y = y + 1
    end
end
```

map.txt :

```
6777633333
6558633333
6555614133
7757711112
2111111112
2111111112
2222222222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use multi-dimensional array like this. See [Matrices and Multi-Dimensional Arrays](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.2.html)

You can transform your code like this :

```
local fmap = love.filesystem.read("map.txt")
map = {}
x = 0
y = 0
map[x] = {}
for c in fmap:gmatch(".") do
    if c == "\n" then
        y = 0
        x = x + 1
        map[x] = {}
    else
        map[x][y] = c -- this won't work
        y = y + 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this has already been answered, but you'd probably find my (in progress) [tile tutorial](https://github.com/kikito/love-tile-tutorial) useful. The [strings section](https://github.com/kikito/love-tile-tutorial/wiki/1d-strings) deals with exactly the issue you are having.